problem on Use Redis++'s coroutine interface with Boost.Asio
I tried to directly use the redis++'s coroutine interface with Boost.Asio, but it didn't work.
for example ,when i try
  boost::asio::co_spawn(ioc, [&co_redis]() -> boost::asio::awaitable<void> {
        auto r = co_await co_redis.command<long long>("setbit", "bmap", 100007, 0) ;
  },boost::asio::detached);

The following error message will be given:
No matching member function for call to 'await_transform'clang(ovl_no_viable_member_function_in_call)
awaitable.hpp(204, 8): Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'Awaiter<long long>' to 'this_coro::executor_t' for 1st argument
awaitable.hpp(230, 8): Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'Awaiter<long long>' to 'this_coro::cancellation_state_t' for 1st argument
awaitable.hpp(255, 8): Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'Awaiter<long long>' to 'this_coro::reset_cancellation_state_0_t' for 1st argument
awaitable.hpp(344, 8): Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'Awaiter<long long>' to 'this_coro::throw_if_cancelled_0_t' for 1st argument
awaitable.hpp(371, 8): Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'Awaiter<long long>' to 'this_coro::throw_if_cancelled_1_t' for 1st argument
awaitable.hpp(439, 8): Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'Awaiter<long long>' to 'detail::awaitable_thread_has_context_switched' for 1st argument
awaitable.hpp(169, 8): Candidate template ignored: could not match 'awaitable' against 'Awaiter'
awaitable.hpp(178, 8): Candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with Op = Awaiter<long long>]: no type named 'type' in 'boost::asio::constraint<false>'
awaitable.hpp(281, 8): Candidate template ignored: could not match 'reset_cancellation_state_1_t' against 'Awaiter'
awaitable.hpp(310, 8): Candidate template ignored: could not match 'reset_cancellation_state_2_t' against 'Awaiter'
awaitable.hpp(402, 8): Candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with Function = Awaiter<long long>]: no type named 'type' in 'boost::asio::result_of<sw::redis::CoRedis::Awaiter<long long> (boost::asio::detail::awaitable_frame_base<boost::asio::any_io_executor> *)>'

Actually, I found a method to solve my problem. I wrote a new Awaiter class to replace original Awaiter  class in the library's header file, as follows:
  template <typename Result,
            typename ResultParser = DefaultResultParser<Result>>
  class Awaiter {
  public:
    template <typename CompletionToken = boost::asio::use_awaitable_t<Result>>
    auto co_exec(CompletionToken &&token = {}) {
      auto initiate = [this]<typename Handler>(Handler &&handler) mutable {
        _async_redis->co_command_with_parser<Result, ResultParser>(
            std::move(_cmd),
            [this, handler = std::move(handler)](Future<Result> &&fut) mutable {
              _result = std::move(fut);
              if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Result, void>) {
                handler();
              } else {
                handler(_result.get());
              }
            });
      };
      if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Result, void>) {
        return boost::asio::async_initiate<CompletionToken, void()>(
            std::move(initiate), token);

      } else {
        return boost::asio::async_initiate<CompletionToken, void(Result)>(
            std::move(initiate), token);
      }
    }

  private:
    friend class CoRedis;
    Awaiter(AsyncRedis *r, FormattedCommand cmd)
        : _async_redis(r), _cmd(std::move(cmd)) {}
    AsyncRedis *_async_redis = nullptr;
    FormattedCommand _cmd;
    Future<Result> _result;
  };

My problem was solved temporarily, but directly changing the source code might not be a good idea.
So, I want to know if there is any method to directly use the coroutine interface with Boost.Asio by adding some external code.
Also, why can't the original awaiter be used with Boost.Asio?
Thank you very much!

What platform/versions are you on? For me redis++ required libuv, cppcoro, but cppcoro hasn't been updated in 4 years and still expects libc++ with experimental/coroutine header. That's not working on my system.

Meanwhile, Boost Cobalt is the generic C++ coroutine library that aims to integrate Asio with other primitives. Also note that Boost.Redis has been accepted into boost jan 27th, being completely based on Asio it might already fit your needs: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_86_0/libs/redis/doc/html/index.html

@sehe Thank for your reply. I work on Linux with Boost version 1.85.0, and I am using a fork of cppcoro. This fork allows me to make the redis++ coroutine interface work in my environment. However, I recall that when I first tried to compile redis++'s coroutine example, I encountered an error. To resolve it, I made a slight change to one of cppcoro's header files (perhaps by adding a const or noexcept specifier).

Okay. That port allows me to compile the README demo at least. (I note that literally ZERO test/example code seems to exercise the coro interface? 100% of available demo code is from the readme). It tells me that redis++ is based on libuv, not Asio. It implies that the event loop is owned by uv. There are strategies to interoperate, but by far the better idea would be to explicitly code your eventloop dependencies, I feel https://stackoverflow.com/a/72939704/85371

And yes the slight change is required for GCC14, not Clang: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VDNNJwSM2R/
